# css3 min-max width when zooming out pages

Tags: html, css, layout, liquid-layout

A good day to you. I am working on a webpage but I got stuck on defining the max and min width. Basically I would want my page to be centered in when zooming out the webpages like what most webpages does. Please need expert help.ASAP thanks.

```
body
{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;

  margin:0 auto; 
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #E5E5E5 30%, #999);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E5E5E5 30%, #999);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #E5E5E5 30%, #999);

}

#mainContainer
{
background-image:url(bg3.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat;
background-color:#999;
width:70%; /*default width in percent for a liquid layout.
the problem is when I zoom out the page the width remains to be in 70% therefore forcing the contents to be pushed to the left corner instead of being centered.*/
min-width:940px; 
margin:5px auto;
height:100%; 
padding:0 1% 0 1%; 
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically this can only be achieved via script.

Get the 70% width of the browser's screen.
Convert that width into its corresponding px value
Set the max width of the #mainContainer using the value got from the conversion/calculation.

```
$( document ).ready( function(){
setMaxWidth();

function setMaxWidth() {
$( "#mainContainer" ).css( "maxWidth", ( $( window ).width() * 0.7 | 0 ) + "px" );
}

});
```

-thanks to Esailija [link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995876/esailija)

Comment: Hi.I used your answer,When page zoom is 100%, then zooming out occurs, it works properly.But if screen zoom is 50% then I load my page:I will not get a good result .
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It centered for me. But have number of potential problems:

1. To apply height 100% to #mainContainer, you need to apply height not only to body, but to html too.
2. Also you need to clear padding and margin on html and body, or they will add scrolls.
3. You can't make margins to container with 100% height or they will add scrolls to page. I emulate them with padding on body and "box-sizing: border-box;", but it will not work correctly in the older IE's, so you will need a hack for them.
4. Also you better change height to min-height, or it will become messy then you will have lot of content inside #mainContainer.

Fixed them here: http://jsfiddle.net/WLPGE/1/

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications and taking some time in looking in to this. Well it improves the layout of my pages. And oh, the pages centered to you? Basically it is indeed at the center when zooming out but thres a bit difference with mine. When you zoom it out the container size stays where it is, but  I want it that when I zoom it out the width itself will also fluidly adapt to the zooming out and not just only the content. its like compressing the content along the width size.

Comment: If I understands correctly, you want #mainContainer to stretch when it's width is more than 940px, right? It is stretching now if 70% of container width is more then min-width (940px). So if you screen width is more than 1350px #mainWidth will start to become wider. If you want in to start stretching right after it will become 940px, you will need to change "width: 70%;" to "width: 100%";" or something like it.

Comment: I want the #mainContainer to limit its width once I zoom it out therefore compressing all of its contents moving it all to the center.  - here is the snapshot of how it originally looks like.  -->[link] http://tinypic.com/r/28wjcci/5   - then this what it looks like when i zoom out my browser. [link]http://tinypic.com/r/102qlcn/5  -this is what i want it to look like when zoomed out. [link]http://tinypic.com/r/2v2uuea/5.

Comment: .see the difference? =D  Basically i know that its the width:70% that causes the dilemma but I cant remove this because my page will then not be liquid with others sizes of screen. i can got what i want it to look if i defined the width or the max-width in px (but then its not applicable for a layout to be liquid).

Comment: Ah, I understand now. But I'm afraid I don't know how to make it zoom and liquid at the same time. :(

Comment: ah. i see. Oh well its fine..Thanks for taking your time to look this up. =D